# Are questions potentially about FCC regulations on TV shows on topic?

Tags: discussion

I've got a question that I want to ask about a show that in one episode censored the word "bitch", yet used it quite freely later on. I want to ask "What happened between the episodes that allowed this?" I could see the answer quite possibly having something to do with FCC regulations, and I just want to know if this would be on topic?

Comment: Yes, it probably would.